# Android Studio GPU monitor will not work for OpenGLES2

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, opengl-es-2.0, monitoring

How can I monitor the GPU usage of my OpenGLES2 app on Android?
The GPU monitor in Android Studio seems to ignore OpenGL GPU usage.

Please note that I have enabled **gpu rendering profile** in **developer options** and set it to **Show in adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo**.

The GPU monitor seems to run, but it looks like the GPU is not even used.

How can I monitor GPU usage for an OpenGLES application?

Thank you !

Comment: Your best bet might be looking at what's been made available by the GPU manufacturer of the device. PowerVR and NVidia both provide GPU profiling tools, they can be fiddly to setup though.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out yet?

Comment: For the recording, I'm trying to get this working on a Samsung Galaxy S7 too. The GPU usage shows as 0, which I know cannot be true.